# MySQL 5.7 Geospatial Index, will points concentrate in one point cause performance matter

Tags: mysql, geolocation, mysql-5.7

I have many images's information store in MySQL, most of image have geo location info but others don't.

Since MySQL geospatial index doesn't allow null geometry point, I have to insert some nonsense point to the table like POINT(1000 1000).

If all images that don't have geo location info are set to POINT(1000 1000) will cause any problem?

Or is there any better way to satisfy this need?

Answer (score 0):

Geospatial index is not needed in such case. Faster and simpler way to do this is to use KEY (lon, lat) and SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE lon > a and lon < b and lat > c and lat < d;

Comment: If the only required functionality was finding images of a bounding area you are right. But geospatial types and functions offer things like distance calculations and the ability to find the points inside a polygon.

Answer (score 0):

`POINT` or `GEOMETRY` can be null in MySQL (using either InnoDB or MyISAM storage engine) However, when you are creating the table the columns must be declared as not null.

Simply do this:

`CREATE TABLE images(filename TEXT, location POINT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO images(filename, location) VALUES ('hello.png', NULL);
SELECT count(*) FROM images WHERE location IS NULL;`